# check if file exist in hdfs with wildcard character

Tags: hadoop

I want to check if a file exist in hdfs or not. I am using

```html
if $(hadoop fs -test -e $myfilewithpath) ; then echo "ok";else echo "not ok"; fi
```

Now I am getting an error message like

```html
test: `/data/bi/udm/incoming/Viewership/year=2016/month=02/day=26/hour=07/part-m-*.avro': No such file or directory
not ok
```

The file which I am expecting in the path can be any mapper output file i.e. it can be `part-m-00000.avro` or it can be `part-m-00099.avro` and that is why I am using `*` in my search like `part-m-*.avro`.

But can we eliminate the below message and get only output as `not ok`

```html
test: `/data/bi/udm/incoming/Viewership/year=2016/month=02/day=26/hour=07/part-m-*.avro': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve it by the below code

```html
if $(hadoop fs -ls $tilldirectorypath|grep "part-m-*.avro") ; then echo "ok";else echo "not ok"; fi
```

```html
Where tilldirectorypath=/data/bi/udm/incoming/Viewership/year=2016/month=02/day=26/hour=07

And previous path defined as myfilewithpath=/data/bi/udm/incoming/Viewership/year=2016/month=02/day=26/hour=07/part-m-*.avro
```